# Best way to set a use control equal to the dimensions of the window it is in

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What is the best way to set a UserControl equal to the container area in a Window in Windows Forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Control.Dock property :)

this.MyUserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;